# Installing a scanner

Tags: 16.04

My Fuji Xerox Docuprint CM115w only installed as a printer and did not recognise the scan function.  How do I add a scanner to hardware?  I can only see how to add a printer.

Comment: Hi, although it's not advisable to post a link only answer, but, due to a large number of steps involved to solve the matter, here goes the link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SANE%20-%20Installing%20a%20scanner%20that%20isn't%20auto-detected

Comment: @ArijitChatterjee the steps aren't much could post as an answer, :)

Comment: @George I was typing through phone, so.. :)

Comment: Ok, but I don't see his model there on the link from the page though!